# Determining the Similarity Between Items in a Database

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp, search-engine, data-mining, full-text-indexing

We have a database with hundreds of millions of records of log data. We're attempting to 'group' this log data as being likely to be of the same nature as other entries in the log database. For instance:

Record X may contain a log entry like:

> Change Transaction ABC123 Assigned To Server US91

And Record Y may contain a log entry like:

> Change Transaction XYZ789 Assigned To Server GB47

To us humans those two log entries are easily recognizable as being likely related in some way. Now, there may be 10 million rows between Record X and Record Y. And there may be thousands of other entries that are similar to X and Y, and some that are totally different but that have other records they are similar to.

What I'm trying to determine is the best way to group the similar items together and say that with XX% certainty Record X and Record Y are probably of the same nature. Or perhaps a better way of saying it would be that the system would look at Record Y and say based on your content you're most like Record X as apposed to all other records.

I've seen some mentions of Natural Language Processing and other ways to find similarity between strings (like just brute-forcing some Levenshtein calculations) - however for us we have these two additional challenges:

1. The content is machine generated - not human generated
2. As opposed to a search engine approach where we determine results for a given query - we're trying to classify a giant repository and group them by how alike they are to one another.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Do you have some example records that look different?  To me, it sounds like a clustering problem.

Comment: i'd recommend hiring a statistician/"data scientist".

Comment: I disagree that this is "not constructive". *Hard* maybe; one could certainly ask for more thought as to what would / would not be considered similar, and how similarity might be "ranked"... But then again, one might just as easily ask for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem.  Obviously, there's a scale issue here because you don't really want to start comparing each record to every other record in the DB.  I believe I'd look at growing a list of "known types" and scoring records against the types in that list to see if each record has a match in that list.

The "scoring" part will hopefully draw some good answers here -- your ability to score against known types is key to getting this to work well, and I have a feeling you're in a better position than we are to get that right.  Some sort of soundex match, maybe?  Or if you can figure out how to "discover" which parts of new records change, you could define your known types as regex expressions.

At that point, for each record, you can hopefully determine that you've got a match (with high confidence) or a match (with lower confidence) or very likely no match at all.  In this last case, it's likely that you've found a new "type" that should be added to your "known types" list.  If you keep track of the score for each record you matched, you could also go back for low-scoring matches and see if a better match showed up later in your processing.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest indexing your data using a text search engine like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) to split your log entries into terms. As your data is machine generated use also word bigrams and tigrams, even higher order n-grams. A bigram is just a sequence of consecutive words, in your example you would have the following bigrams:

```
Change_Transaction, Transaction_XYZ789, XYZ789_Assigned, Assigned_To, To_Server, Server_GB47
```

For each log prepare queries in a similar way, the search engine may give you the most similar results. You may need to tweek the similarity function a bit to obtain best results but I believe this is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Two main strategies come to my mind here:

1. the ad-hoc one. Use an information retrieval approach. Build an index for the log entries, eventually using a specialized tokenizer/parser, by feeding them into a regular **text search engine**. I've heard people do this with Xapian and Lucene. Then you can "search" for a new log record and the text search engine will (hopefully) return some related log entries to compare it with. Usually the "information retrieval" approach is however only interested in finding the 10 most similar results.
2. the clustering approach. You will usually need to turn the data into numerical vectors (that may however be sparse) e.g. as TF-IDF. Then you can apply a **clustering algorithm** to find groups of closely related lines (such as the example you gave above), and investigate their nature. You might need to tweak this a little, so it doesn't e.g. cluster on the server ID.

Both strategies have their ups and downs. The first one is quite fast, however it will always just return you some similar existing log lines, without much quantities on how common this line is. It's mostly useful for human inspection.

The second strategy is more computationally intensive, and depending on your parameters could fail completely (so maybe test it on a subset first), but could also give more useful results by actually building large groups of log entries that are very closely related.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could take the lucene approach mentioned above, then use that as a source for input vectors into the machine learning library Mahout (http://mahout.apache.org/). Once there you can train a classifier, or just use one of their clustering algorithms.

Answer (score -2):

If your DBMS has it, take a look at SOUNDEX().